# mobile menu is not showing

Tags: mobile, responsive

I run a website using WordPress. The hello elementor theme was utilised. My header desktop view header menu is displaying appropriately, which is my concern.but the hamburger menu in mobile view does not display. Please help .www.whitebricksme.com - check mobile view . menu will not show.

Comment: You'll have to ask your theme's support team for help. Third-party theme support is [off topic](/help/on-topic) here.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with the Hello Elementor theme and the mobile menu.
I found an option that worked for me and that was to disable the Built-in Icon Fonts feature in Elementor settings.

[image]

Hope it works for you